# SWT TextBox Write is much slower then C++ executable prints

Tags: java, c++

I am creating a Java GUI which interacts with C++ executable using ProcessBuilder. All the InputStream, OutputStream, ErrorStream from the C++ executable are redirected to the GUI TextBox. The C++ executable is very fast and it outputs lots of messages. Now the problem is eventhough the C++ executable is completed execution, GUI is still printing those messages over TextBox (as I am creating Display thread to write into GUI TextBox) for another 5-6 Minutes. Is there any way I can sync GUI-TextBox write speed with that of C++ executable prints? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

One idea see if it works for you:

Don't try to refresh the gui with every messages coming from c++. Try to buffer them and minimize the number of callbacks you do for GUI refresh. You cannot decide upfront a good buffer size that you can flush to GUI. You may have to do this fine tuning by trying different buffer sizes and limiting the number of GUI refresh through callback.

Hope it helps!